# how to change in magento shipping method

Tags: php, magento

– In my store if user buy product than shipping cost will added on the basis of the weight of the product but after the certain shipping amount let say after $100 I don’t want to add any further shipping cost to it. is this possible in magento? Please help me on this...

Comment: yes, checking Shopping Cart Rules in admin end i guess..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes there is shopping cart rule you can set

here is very good example with screen shot just go throw [this link](http://www.phpro.be/news/configuring-shopping-cart-price-rules-magento-free-shipping)

and also for weight dependent shipping you can set by [this way](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-set-up-table-rate-shipping) or [this one](http://blog.baobaz.com/en/blog/how-to-use-magento-shipping-table-rates)

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: thanks for the answer i will implement that solution.

Comment: will please accept my answer if it is useful to you. so some one can have same issue in future so they can utilize our thread